# How to merge two TextView

Tags: android, textview

I want a view like below.

> **[TEXTVIEW_WITH_BACKGROUND]** Long long description covers left textview. This is a very long long description. This long long description is a very long textview without background.

The background image is a 9-patch, so it's width changes dynamically.

I'm not sure that you understood. Sorry for poor English.

I found google and stackoverflow for a whole day, but couldn't found anything.

If you had ever did something like this, please give a small tip.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to do this stuff using one TextView then you must have to use Spannable text. But I am not suggesting it. Another way is, declare 2 TextView one for background text and second one is for long long description.

Comment: @pratik Thank you for the comment!
I thought about two textviews, but the long long textview's shape is not rectangular.(because of the background textview) :(

Comment: For a task like this, I would go with web view and show html text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. I found the answer myself.

https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Spannable

This repo helped me.

Answer (score 0):

//Try this

You have to do it using Html.fromHTML().

See below example you will get better idea.

```
YOURTEXTVIEW.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='green'><b>" + YOUR BACKGROUND TEXT + "</b></font>" + "  "+ YOUR LONG LONG TEXT));
```

Comment: It will work for background as well, ask try to put HTML background code instead of font color, it will surely work.

Comment: But if my answer is looking useful in any sense then please mark it up or do right.